Using PuppeteerSharp to generate webPage to PDF but losing color
I am using PuppeteerSharp(ver 18.0.5.0) to generate webPage to PDF.
This is my WebPage view ⬇
WebPage view
After using Puppeteer to download, this is what my PDF file shows ⬇
PDF file view
Here is my PdfOptions setting
await page.PdfAsync(pdfPath, new PdfOptions
{
    Format = PaperFormat.A4,
    PrintBackground = true,
    PreferCSSPageSize = true,
});

And below is css setting.
@media print {
    @page {
        margin: 22mm 15mm 35mm 15mm;
        background-color: teal !important;
    }

    html, body, #content, #header, #footer, .page {
        background-color: teal !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
    }
}

if I print to PDF by using chrome, it would be like this ⬇

Since my content are from Editor.
I have been setting PrintBackground attr, and setting css, but none of these are working.

What do you get if you print to PDF using chrome?

Hi, Hardoded. I put it on post.

I think you need to remove the setting Format = PaperFormat.A4, and in the css @page add size: a4 portrait; or your preferred size/orientation in css.

turn on:  printBackground: true,
        pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true,
            margin: {
                top: '0mm',
                right: '0mm',
                bottom: '0mm',
                left: '0mm'
            }
        });

